# PhoneGap nfc listener remove/close

Tags: cordova, listener, nfc, event-listener

I have the following problem:

Ii have a website with two buttons:
first button should write some data on a mifare classic 1k tag
second button should read some data from a mifare classic 1k tag

When I push the first button I call `nfc.addMimeTypeListener('text/pg',writeTag,win,fail);`

writeTag is a function which write the data on my tag with nfc.write(...).

My problem is now that after pushing the first button the first Listener is open and after pushing the second button the first listener is still open. When I want to read something from a tag my first listener writes something on the tag and the second listener (read) reads after the first event.

I need something to close/remove a nfc.addMimeTypeListener.

Does somebody can help me?
thx, mark

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Android, removing listeners isn't implemented.

I add NFC listeners when deviceready fires and leave them for the lifetime of the application.

I recommend having you're application know if it's in read or write mode.

When you're in read mode, don't try writing the tag. Try something like

```
var writeTag = function(nfcEvent) {
    if (app.mode == WRITE) {
        nfc.write(...)
    }
}
```